# starting windows application with powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I need to start up Outlook via Powershell script and schedule it.

The Powershell script is able to start Outlook when its run manually from powershell command prompt.

But when the same script is run via windows task scheduler I only see the process kicking off in background while there is no running instance of Outlook in the front end.

I wanted to know why the app is not launching at the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what user the scheduled task is running as, unless it's running as the logged in user you won't see anything.

Outlook will launch, as a background process, but as it will be running as another user (likely system) you won't see the outlook window.

[image: scheduled task example]